# Next.js development environment breaks layout and shows error about image rendering. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, image, npm, next.js, styled-components

I'm having a problem within my development environment of my Next.js application, the problem consists of a completely broken layout, and an error referring to my image "Image with src "...paths..." may not render correctly with a parent using position:"static". Consider changing the parent style to position:"relative" with width and height."

The parent element has absolute position with its dimensions defined inside another element which is relative, this was working great until a while ago, but now I can't do anything else in my project.

Another point is that if I build the application it works perfectly, and when I start it too, only in my dev environment it doesn't work at all.

Has anyone been through this situation?

I feel that the styled-components is not working and that's why this problem in the layout, and even adding this to a class it still has the same problem.

Comment: A small code sample that exhibits the problem would be helpful.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. @LaurenzAlbe it's a bit hard to share code samples, generally next.js app are pretty big.

Comment: @0plus1 Well, you'd have to make the effort to create a minimal application that exhibits the problem. If it is not a matter of the application code, but a bug in next.js, you had best report that to the authors.